# For loop and see variable name as a string in R

Tags: r

I want to create a for loop in R, but it should depend on the last letter in 17 variables, and I have trouble finding out how to make the function see the variable name as a string.

The code I have now:

```
fisher.test(table( data.family$proband.unrelated, data.family$q_81_SQ00a)) 
fisher.test(table( data.family$proband.unrelated, data.family$q_81_SQ00b)) 
fisher.test(table( data.family$proband.unrelated, data.family$q_81_SQ00c))
```

As you can see, i just keep on repeating the code for each variable from the letter a to r, so i want to create a for loop, which can change the last letter of the variable q_81_SQ00a to the letters a-r.

```
for (i in c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r')) {

  fisher.test(data.family$proband.unrelated, data.family$q_81_SQ00'i'))  

}
```

I get the warning "unexpected symbol" for several places in the code. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example with data? I think there are better ways to do this in R than using a for loop, e.g. dplyr or data.table using groups (group_by or by).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the comments, it seems you have some trouble with some of the Fisher tests. To see which go right and wrong, you could add the `try` function around the Fisher test.

```
lapply(letters[1:18], function(x){
    try(fisher.test(table(data.family$proband.unrelated,
                data.family[[paste0("q_81_SQ00", x)]])))
})
```

Comment: The original code that you implicitly stated worked, included a `table` call while your loop attempt did not. I have kept that call although that is mere guesswork since I do not know what your data looks like. Perhaps you could add a `str(data.family)` to the bottom of your question?

Comment: That worked for me! All the p values i get from your code is the same as when i run fishers test seperate for each variable - thanks! I think it was the lapply, can't see what else.

Comment: When using the `lapply`, we make the call inside a function. We can then use `try`, which allows us to run through the code even if some of the elements cause errors. [You could circumvent the issue in a `for` loop also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14748557/3560695), however the use of `lapply` just conveniently puts the results in a combined list, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You have to paste the letter to the variable name to get a character string, and then select the desired variable using the `[]` operator. 
Another hint: the `letters` constant in R contains letters from a to z.

Here is a solution:

```
for (i in letters[1:18]) {
  fisher.test(data.family["proband.unrelated"],
              data.family[paste0("q_81_SQ00", i)])  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to run it, but i get the warning: 'x' and 'y' must have the same length

Comment: @JulieRavn that has nothing to do with the provided code but is all because (at least) one of your `q_81_SQ00` elements from the `data.family` differ in length from the `proband.unrelated` one. Fisher's test requires the length of `x` and `y` to be equal.

Comment: Thanks @Therkel! You were right - two of the 17 variables had the option '3' instead of just '1' and '2'. But i still get an error (sorry, i'm a newbie in R!): " 'x' must have at least 2 rows and columns". And i've checked - there are two outcomes for each variable now.