# How to continue a loop when NA/NaN/Inf error occurs in depmixS4 HMM fitting?

Tags: r, loops, machine-learning, error-handling

code:

```
for(j in 1:100){......     
for(k in 1:20) {
        fit.mod = fit(mod)
        if(AIC(fit.mod) < best) { best_model = fit.mod 
        best = AIC(fit.mod)
        } 
      fit.mod <- best_model
........}
```

when the error

```
Error in fb(init = init, A = trDens, B = dens, ntimes = ntimes(object),  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)
```

occurs, the loop automatically stops. 
I tried

```
if(is.na(fit.mod)){next}
```

and

```
if(!identical(fit.mod@message,c("Log likelihood converged to within tol. (relative change)"))){next}
```

But the loop still stops. Is there a method where I can ignore this error and continue the loop? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `try` function. There should be worked examples on SO already. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+error+try+catch

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realize that this question has nothing to do with HMM

Comment: I edited your tags to make them more on topic.

Comment: Thx. The answer is: if(inherits(try(fit(mod)),"try-error")){next}

Comment: Looks ok. You might want to have an `else{.}` in there as well.

Comment: Oops..the method "inherits"can detect error but the loop still stops. The right answer is here"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748557/skipping-error-in-for-loop

Thank for your help!

Comment: Generally one would attempt to assign the results of a fit-operation to a value so that it can then be examined when there is no error.