# skip errors triggered by the package `rstan` in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, stan

As stated in the title, I wanted to skip errors triggered by `rstan` in a for loop in R and let the loop continue running. I know there are similar answers suggesting `tryCatch()` or `try()`, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748557/skipping-error-in-for-loop). However, they do not work when the error originates from `stan` within a loop. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(rstan)

stancode = 'data {
  int<lower=0> J;          // number of schools
  real y[J];               // estimated treatment effects
  real<lower=0> sigma[J];  // s.e. of effect estimates
}
parameters {
  real mu;
  real<lower=0> tau;
  vector[J] eta;
}
transformed parameters {
  vector[J] theta;
  theta = mu + tau * eta;
}
model {
  target += normal_lpdf(eta | 0, 1);
  target += normal_lpdf(y | theta, sigma);
}'

schools_data <- list(
  J = 8,
  y = c(28,  8, -3,  7, -1,  1, 18, 12),
  sigma = c(-15, 10, 16, 11,  9, 11, 10, 18)#Intentionally created a negative value here
)

for (i in 1:3) {
  tryCatch({fit1 <- stan(model_code  = stancode, data = schools_data,
               chains = 1, iter = 1000, refresh = 0)}, error=function(e){})
}
```

The answer is not supposed to fix the negative value, but skipping the stan error in a for loop. Thank you!

Comment: Did the answer help you by any chance? If so, please mark it as accepted that the community is aware of it. Otherwise, point to what is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system has troubles to run the stan code but did you try `purrr`s `safely()` or `possibly()`?

```
x <- list(1, "d", 3)
purrr::map(x, ~1/.x)
# error in 1/.x: non numeric argument for binary operator
purrr::map(x, safely(~1/.x))
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$result
# [1] 1
#  
# [[1]]$error
# NULL
#  
#  
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$result
# NULL
#  
# [[2]]$error
# <simpleError in 1/.x: non numeric argument for binary operator>
#   
#   
# [[3]]
# [[3]]$result
# [1] 0.3333333
#  
# [[3]]$error
# NULL
```