# How to return the index causing an error in R

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, try-catch

I'm working on a loop, and I want to extract the index causing an error in R and put it into a separate object.

Here is an example modified from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748557/skipping-error-in-for-loop) in a stack overflow post. It skips and reports the nature of the error.

```
for (i in 1:15) {
  tryCatch({
    print(i)
    if (i==7) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==9) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==14) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")

  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}
```

In addition to skipping and reporting the error, how can I improve this code to create a separate object with the index causing the error? Such that, it creates an object, `Index Error`, with 7, 9, and 14 inside it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `<<-` operator to save the index of the error.

```
var <- c()
for (i in 1:15) {
  tryCatch({
    print(i)
    if (i==7) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==9) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==14) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    
  }, error=function(e){
    cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")
    var <<- c(var, i)
    })
}

var
#[1]  7  9 14
```

Comment: Wow, that's really cool! Didn't know that `<<-` was a possibility. I'll have to read up on it! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways, both with a `lapply` loop, only different in what the error function returns.
The error messages are displayed with `message`, not `cat`. This is because the use of `cat` or `print` in packages is frowned upon.

### 1. Return the index `i`

```
result <- lapply(1:15, function(i) {
  tryCatch({
    print(i)
    if (i==7) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==9) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==14) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    
  }, error=function(e){
    msg <- paste("ERROR :", conditionMessage(e))
    message(msg)
    i
  })
})
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
#[1] 6
#[1] 7
#ERROR : Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !
#[1] 8
#[1] 9
#ERROR : Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !
#[1] 10
#[1] 11
#[1] 12
#[1] 13
#[1] 14
#ERROR : Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !
#[1] 15

unlist(result)
#[1]  7  9 14
```

### 2. Return the error `e`

This solution returns the error itself, which can latter be retrieved. The output of `message` is ommited.

```
result <- lapply(1:15, function(i) {
  tryCatch({
    print(i)
    if (i==7) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==9) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    if (i==14) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
    
  }, error=function(e){
    msg <- paste("ERROR :", conditionMessage(e))
    message(msg)
    e
  })
})

err <- which(sapply(result, inherits, "error"))
err
#[1]  7  9 14

result[[14]]$message
#[1] "Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !"
```