# using tryCatch in R to skip errors inside of loop

Tags: r, try-catch

I'm attempting to use tryCatch to skip instances of a function generating errors inside of a for loop so that the loop completes and generates output values in those instances where there are no errors. Here's a toy example whose output makes little sense to me:

```
list=list(10,20,"abc",30,40)
y=c()
for(x in list1){
   skip_to_next = FALSE
   temp=tryCatch(log(x), error = function(e) {skip_to_next = TRUE})
   if(skip_to_next) {next}
   y=c(y,temp)
}
```

If I execute this for loop, my output y is:

```
y
[1] 2.302585 2.995732 1.000000 3.401197 3.688879
```

I'm not sure where the 1.0 is coming from, log of a string throws an error and should just skip the third iteration entirely, i.e. return a 4-element vector with elements 1:2 and 4:5 of the above.

Evidently I'm not implementing tryCatch() or next correctly - why isn't "next" taking me to the next iteration as I thought it should?

I was referencing this previous stackoverflow discussion when writing my example:

[Skipping error in for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748557/skipping-error-in-for-loop)

Comment: An alternative, avoiding a loop that grows an object*, would be: `list1 |> Filter(f = is.numeric) |> sapply(FUN = log)` * see Circle 2 in the R-Inferno: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the super-assignment:

```r
tryCatch(log(x), error = function(e) {skip_to_next <<- TRUE})
```

In your code, you do

```r
temp <- tryCatch(log(x), error = function(e) {skip_to_next = TRUE})
```

Then in `temp` you have the output of the `error` function, which is `TRUE` (see below) but it is coerced to `1` in the numeric vector `y`.

Here is why the output is `TRUE`:

```r
f <- function() {
  a <- 2
}

print(f())
# 2
```